# Comment saluer les coureurs ?

Tags: registre-familier, politesse, salutations

Je suis un coureur (à pied) arrivé récemment en France, et suis un peu surpris par la politesse irréprochable des français.

Ainsi, j'ai un problème quand je rencontre des coureurs comme moi. Je n'avais pas l'habitude de les saluer, mais quelques-uns le font, je crois qu'ils disent *bonjour*. J'essaie de le faire moi-même, même sans le contact visuel. Mais *bonjour* n'est-il pas trop distant? Pourquoi pas "salut", bien que je n'ai entendu personne l'utiliser encore, ici ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Bonjour" est exactement ce qu'il faut dire. Il est toujours acceptable et n'est jamais distant. "Salut" ne pourrait être éventuellement utilisé qu'avec des coureurs avec qui vous avez déjà noué connaissance et êtes suffisamment familiers (ou entre enfants/ados).

Comment: Un autre signe, entre reconnaissance et le « bonjour » que j'utilise, est le signe de tête (hochement en acquiescement et en fermant les yeux). Il est plus distant et plus froid que le bonjour si on est timide, mais le message passe de la même manière. À ce moment-là, c'est moi qui l'initie, car si la personne me dit « bonjour », je répondrais par « bonjour » pour rester sur le même temps. Un avantage de ce signe, c'est quand on est à une certaine distance mais dans le même champ de vision.

Answer (score 5):

I think “salut” is over-friendly. Perhaps could be used when you meet them more often and after you chat up at least a couple of times and regularly thereafter. Or if you intend to meet up again later on (same day).
No strings attached with “Bonjour” though

Answer (score 3):

A vrai dire, cela dépend du ton employé. En disant *Bonjour*, il n'y a pas de risque de passer pour quelqu'un d'un peu trop amical, ce qui dans le cas d'un coureur que l'on connait pas est tout à fait adéquat. On peut par cependant paraître un peu distant.

Dire *Salut* avec un ton sympathique peut également être utilisé dans ce cas. Cela montre une certaine sympathie envers une personne qui possède la même passion pour la course à pied. C'est plus personnel et cela pourrait améliorer l'ambiance et rapprocher un groupe de coureurs.